# WSGI on Windows/IIS behind reverse proxy, how to set up multiple processes and process recycling?

Tags: python, windows, iis, wsgi

I have previously deployed CPython apps on IIS using [isapi-wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/isapi-wsgi/), and this has worked well for a handful of cases.

However on my current project I have run into difficulties with isapi-wsgi: The combination of Windows Server 2008 R2, 64-bit Python and the pyodbc module will not work without me recompiling the pyodbc module (at least this is what half an hour of googling leads me to believe).

Anyway: I have decided I will try another option for deploying WSGI on Windows for this project.

The plan is:

- IIS web server configured for reverse proxying (using IIS [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/planning-for-arr/application-request-routing-version-2-overview))
- A Python process hosted as a windows service handling the requests passed on from IIS, like [this example](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/deployment/windows.html#step-2-create-a-windows-service) from the Pylons project

My questions:

- It would be great if my Python process could spin up N long-running request handling processes and automatically distribute requests between them.
- It would be great if the Python request handling processes would automatically recycle after a given number of requests.
- Does anyone have tips for how to accomplish the above?

Comment: You might want to ask author of [Everything you wanted to know about deploying web apps on Windows but were too horrified to ask](http://pyvideo.org/video/1611/)

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully used both Paste and CherryPy. Paste is not currently Python 3 compatible and is not likely to grow that support. If Python 3 is something you care about then you will probably want to look at something other than Paste.

I also played with using Twisted as a WSGI server in a service. This worked but I never put it into production because I didn't find it offered the benefits I was looking for over what I was already using.

I'm not familiar with Werkzeug's server so am hesitant to make any comment about the veracity of not using it in production deployments or whether that just means without using a reverse proxy.

Fundamentally any of the well known WSGI servers that run on Windows are likely to be the "best" for some value of "best" depending on your criteria.